# No puedo ejecutar php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel

He estado intentando correr mi sitio que esta publicado en la web pero me daba este error:

> chdir error (): No such file or directory (errno 2)

sin embargo hice lo que consegui en [este post de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873773/laravel5-chdir-no-such-file-or-directory-errno-2), ejecuté de nuevo e `php artisan serve` y ahora me muestra otro error:

> Warning: require_once (C: \ Users \ wacks \ Desktop \ TEC \ webtec / public / index.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C: \ Users \ wacks \ Desktop \ TEC \ webtec \ server.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: require_once (): Failed opening required 'C: \ Users \ wacks \ Desktop \ TEC \ webtec / public / index.php' (include_path = 'C: \ xampp_1 \ php \ PEAR') in C: \ Users \ wacks \ Desktop \ TEC \ webtec \ server.php on line 21

Dejo acá mi código de lo que cambie, a ver si alguien podría ayudarme.

SERVE.PHP

```
<?php

 namespace App\Console\Commands;

 use Exception;
 use Illuminate\Console\Command;
 use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
 use Symfony\Component\Process\PhpExecutableFinder;
 use Symfony\Component\Process\ProcessUtils;

 class Serve extends Command {
/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'serve';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Serve the application on the PHP development server';

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function fire() {
    chdir('/');

    $host = $this->input->getOption('host');

    $port = $this->input->getOption('port');

    $base = ProcessUtils::escapeArgument($this->laravel->basePath());

    $binary = ProcessUtils::escapeArgument((new PhpExecutableFinder)->find(false));

    $this->info("Laravel development server started on http://{$host}:{$port}/");

    if (defined('HHVM_VERSION')) {
        if (version_compare(HHVM_VERSION, '3.8.0') >= 0) {
            passthru("{$binary} -m server -v Server.Type=proxygen -v Server.SourceRoot={$base}/ -v Server.IP={$host} -v Server.Port={$port} -v Server.DefaultDocument=server.php -v Server.ErrorDocument404=server.php");
        } else {
            throw new Exception("HHVM's built-in server requires HHVM >= 3.8.0.");
        }
    } else {
        passthru("{$binary} -S {$host}:{$port} {$base}/server.php");
    }
}

/**
 * Get the console command options.
 *
 * @return array
 */
protected function getOptions() {
    return [
        ['host', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The host address to serve the application on.', 'localhost'],

        ['port', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The port to serve the application on.', 8000],
    ];
}
 }
```

KERNEL.PHP

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Console;

 use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

 class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel {
/**
 * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $commands = [
    // Commands\Inspire::class,
    Commands\Serve::class,
];

/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    // $schedule->command('inspire')
    //  ->hourly();
}
 }
```

WEBTEC/SERVER.PHP

```
 <?php

 /**
  * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
  *
  * @package  Laravel
  * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
  */

 $uri = urldecode(
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
 );

 // This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
 // built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
 // application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
 if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
return false;
 }

 require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Asegúrate de que tu antivirus no te haya jugado una mala pasada. En mi caso tuve un problema similar porque el antivirus daba falsos positivos con ciertos scripts, en Laravel y Angular, y me los mandaba al baúl de virus sin más, con lo que desaparecían de su ubicación original.

En mi caso concreto, utilizo Avast. Lo que hago es que desactivo los escudos antes de ejecutar php artisan serve y, una vez arrancado el server, vuelvo a levantar los escudos. Si se levantan con artisan serve arrancado, ya no me da problemas.